# Why this ToArray() extension method of IEnumerable throws ArrayTypeMismatchException?

Tags: .net, vb.net, exception, ienumerable

why the next example throws a System.ArrayTypeMismatchException?

```
New Int16(){4,5,6}.Cast(of UInt16).ToArray()
```

I expected that this line returned a UInt16 array containing 4,5 and 6.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bug in `Cast` or `ToArray`, IMO. The code in this answer is in C#, but hopefully you can see what it's about :)

I believe that `Cast` first tries to see if a simple reference conversion will work - i.e. where it can return the same reference back.

For example:

```
String x = "hello";
IEnumerable<char> y = x.Cast<char>();
Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)); // Prints true
```

Unfortunately, it does this using the CLR rules for compatibility - under which `UInt16[]` and  `Int16[]` *are* compatible. That leads to this happening:

```
short[] array = new short[]{4, 5, 6};
IEnumerable<ushort> cast = array.Cast<ushort>();
Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(array, cast)); // Prints True
```

Unfortunately if you then try to call `ToArray()`, it's not happy:

```
// Explicit type argument just for clarity
cast.ToArray<ushort>(); // Bang
```

`ToArray` no doubt tries to do some optimisation - which fails in this particular case because the type isn't what it really expects it to be.

I believe the *correct* behaviour should be for `Cast` to return a lazy iterator, but for that to fail when it executes later. That's what happens if you try to go from `Int16` to `Int32`, for example.

Now, to get back to what you *really* want to do: use a `Select` call instead. `Cast` is only meant to be for unboxing operations and reference type conversions.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunatelly I have no knowledge about LINQ still and I always have more urgents things to do, you know. Thanks again anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Because [Int16](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int16.aspx) and [UInt16](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uint16.aspx) are different types. You could try this:

```
New Int16() {4, 5, 6}.Select(Function(x) CType(x, UInt16)).ToArray()
```

Comment: That's why I'm calling Cast isn't it? If they where the same type no Cast would be needed.

Comment: `Cast` works only if the types are compatible (one derives from another). `Int16` and `UInt16` have nothing in common.

Comment: Ok, so is there a way of doing the same thing with a CType instead of with a DirectCast?

Comment: You could do this instead: `New Int16() {4, 5, 6}.Select(Function(x) CType(x, UInt16)).ToArray()`